# How to make a some part of text align right in html

Tags: html

I have my Header and I need to show a text as below,

```
Dashboard                                   User_1
```

Simply the Dashboard should be in left side while user_1 should be at the right side. My Header as follows,

```
<div class="header">Dashboard  <a href="updatedetails.php" style="text-align:right"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></a></div>
```

But this provides both `Dashboard User_1` at the same place. Can someone help me to seperate those two as I required?

update:

If I need to use another text at the right of username? what would be the change to do? Then Dashboard to be at left corner while username and the other text should be in right side.

```
Dashboard                                   User_1 Logout
```

Comment: `style="float:right"` or look into using flexbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend looking into flexbox. This is just a simple example to get you started, but this will be a lot more flexible as you scale up or down resolutions on different devices.

CSS Tricks provides [a guide for flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) too that would be worth a read for you.

You may not be able to use this exact code I have, but it should be a decent jumping-off point for you at least.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 98vw;">
  <div class="flex">
    <a>Dashboard</a>
    <div>
      <a>username</a>
      <a>logout</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked fine. But I have replaced <div style="width: 98vw;"> with <div style="width: 100%"> to fit in to the screen. Unless I need to scroll it to see the username. Thank you very much

Comment: Yeah, I only added the view width to make it fill the screen width, definitely adjust it however you need!

Comment: If I need to use another text at the right of username? what would be the change to do? Then Dashboard to be at left corner while username and the other text should be in right side. I have updated the question as well.

Comment: There are a few different ways to do that, however, the easiest one and the one I'd probably start with is just wrapping those two links in a div. I've updated my answer to reflect that. With flexbox, there can be multiple ways to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways you can achieve it. You can use flex or float.

Using flex with `justify-content: space-between`
Using float: `left` and `right`

```css
.flex-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-header">
  Dashboard
  <a href="updatedetails.php">Sample text</a>
</div>


<div class="header">
  <span class="left">Dashboard</span>
  <a class="right" href="updatedetails.php">Sample text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: We were typing at the same moment haha. I'm curious why you're recommending float in this instance? It's really limiting in terms of placement which is why flexbox is generally more recommended.

Is it just cause float is easier in the short term?

Comment: hehe yeah no specific reason. just giving options on how the OP issue can be resolved by a simple css float property as long as text content is wrapped in an html tag like a `span` :)

Answer (score 0):

An < a> tag is an inline element.
You can use display: flex for example:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;"> 
   <div>
      Dashboard
   </div>
   <a href="updatedetails.php" style="text-align:right"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></a>
</div>
```